# How to use Angular two way binding from Google Maps directionsService.route() function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-maps

Here my Angular Component

```
export class MapsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('googleMap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;  
  data = "initialised";

  ngOnInit() {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

      var map =  new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
            zoom: 7,
            center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
      });
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsService.route({
          origin: "terrell hills, tx",
          destination: "alamo heights, tx",
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        },  (response, status) => {
          if (String(status) === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";
            /***********************************************
             here some string is assigned to this.data, but it was not updated in the "data" member of this class. The value of the member "data" is always showing "initialised" in the HTML template.
             ***********************************************/
          } else {
            alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my Template

```
<span>{{data}}</span> <!-------------here the the data is always showing "initialised"-------------->
```

Can someone please tell me what is the problem.

- The value of `alert(this.data)` before the line `this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";` is **initialised**
- The value of `alert(this.data)` after the line `this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";` is **I'm modified in directionsService**
- But the main class member `data` is not updating.
- I've also tried creating another function `function testFunc(x:any) { this.data = x; }` Now calling this function `this.testFunc("some text")` from `ngOnInit()` is successfully updating the `data` But calling the function `this.testFunc("some text inside directionsService.route")` from `directionsService.route` is not updating the value of `data`
- I've also tried `var self = this` outside the function and `self.data = "some text with self"` is also not working.

Can someone please help me with this? Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change is not being detected as it is happening outside of the angular framework within the google directions callback. You have a few options. I will list them from conceptually easiest to hardest.

**Force Change Detection**

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){}
....
if (String(status) === 'OK') {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    this.data = "I'm modified in directionsService";
    this.ref.detectChanges();
...
```

**Run in Angular2 Zone**

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {}
...
this.ngZone.run(() => {
    -- Run directions query here
});
...
```

**Wrap the directions call in an observable**

```
const directionsObservable = Observbable.create(observer => {
    directionsService.route({
      origin: "terrell hills, tx",
      destination: "alamo heights, tx",
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    },  (response, status) => {
      if (String(status) === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        observer.next("I'm modified in directionsService");
      } else {
        alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
  }
});
directionsObservable.subscribe(text => this.data = text);
```

I have used a very simple example of how an observable would work. You should probably extract the directions call to a seperate service, and use the observable method there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I've not tried the `NgZone` and `Observable`. `ChangeDetectorRef` is worked perfectly. I think those remaining two concepts are useful in many situations. Once again Thank you @Jags

Comment: `ChangeDetectorRef` is a good enough solution here. I don't think `NgZone` has as many applicable use cases. I highly recommend learning to use `Observables` wherever you can. Angular is heavily integrated with `rxjs` and the reactive model is very suited to event driven applications.

Comment: this.data will not be found inside of directionsService.route()